# Monaco editor error: Script error for "jquery", needed by: vs/editor/editor.main

Tags: javascript, jquery, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I'm using require.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.min.js"></script>
```

Code to create editor

```
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '/monaco-editor/min/vs' }});
     require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {                
        monacoEditor= monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('coding-editor'), {
            value: [
            'function x() {',
            '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");',
            '}'
        ].join('\n'),
        language: 'javascript'
        });
     });
```

I'm also using much or jquery and javascript on this page. 
I'm using jquery-1.12.2.min.js on this page.

I'm getting following error,

> Script error for "jquery", needed by: vs/editor/editor.main